# TypeScript property decorator that takes a parameter of the decorated property type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-decorator

I am trying to write a `Default` decorator, so that this would work:

```js
class A {
  @Default(() => new Date())
  test: Date;
}
```

I am trying to achieve strong typing, so that the decorator parameter is either (1) of the decorated property type, or (2) a parameterless function returning a value of the decorated property type.

I tried the following:

```js
type DefaultParam<T> = T | (() => T);

export function Default<K extends string, T extends Record<K, V>, V>(param: DefaultParam<V>): (t: T, p: K) => void {
  return (target: T, propertyKey: K) => {
    // Probably irrelevant
  };
}
```

This, however, fails with:

```
Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, Date>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'A'.
```

Specifying the type parameters, however, works as expected:

```js
class A {
  @Default<'test', A, Date>(() => new Date())
  test: Date;
}
```

Is there a way to write the decorator so that inference works as expected, to avoid explicitly specifying the parameter in the `Default` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the main problem here is that the curried decorator function can't infer a specification for the `K` type parameter (or the `T` type parameter) when you use it.  If you have a curried generic function with a type like:

```
declare const curryBad: <T, U>(t: T) => (u: U) => [T, U]
```

the compiler will try to infer `T` and `U` when you call it.  Let's say you call `curryBad(1)`.  The `1` value causes `T` to be inferred as `number`.  But there's no value of type `U` here, and thus type inference fails for `U` and it becomes `unknown`.  The result of `curryBad(1)` is therefore `(u: unknown) => [number, unknown]`:

```
const bad = curryBad(1)(""); // [number, unknown]
```

While it's not inconceivable that a compiler might theoretically defer inferring `U` until the returned function is called, that's not the way it works in practice.  Instead, you can just write the function's signature that way to begin with: don't declare `U` as a parameter of the initial function; declare it as a parameter of the returned function instead:

```
declare const curryGood: <T>(t: T) => <U>(u: U) => [T, U]
```

Now calling `curryGood(1)` will return a value of type `<U>(u: U) => [number, U]`, which is probably what you want:

```
const good = curryGood(1)(""); // [number, string]
```

---

With that in mind, I'd suggest moving your `K` parameter.  Also, I'm not sure you really need `T` to be its own generic type; `Record<K, V>` might be good enough.  But if you find you do need it, it should also be moved along with `K`:

```
export function Default<V>(
  param: DefaultParam<V>): <K extends PropertyKey>(t: Record<K, V>, p: K) => void {
  return <K extends PropertyKey>(target: Record<K, V>, propertyKey: K) => {    
  };
}
```

And now your decorator should hopefully work as desired:

```
class Good {
  @Default(() => new Date()) // no error
  test!: Date;
}

class Bad {
  @Default(123) // error! Date is not number
  test!: Date; 
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF0QVxjAngEJTABc8APACoA08AqgHwAUG5VAlPALyPzPZy9Lr3gBtWgwC6AWABQoSLATJ0WMLgIBxJEjKUqLNvE48+FJgKEi+EuvVlzVmeACMSPHHiIlmARg5mACIgjgBueAB6SPEUbABbVxAYOmwUAGsUJAB3FEdnLABzXWBPDW8dPX9AkPComLE4xOS6TBgASxRCx3kMfAAHBAAREAAzKGwIDAAFWCh46j5uE3gAH35mGxNw+XkQAA9+pBgsUbSwDHbUeBHxyYwKADUWeXh4frn48luJqdmYeZPRgccgUADS8AOGBAKGAaHg0xgSEGJ3wYJA+CM5AASuBjsBwXRnnR+uQwVsAG5IdqlADer3gcAwuBQlAhUJhcIRSJRfXRmNYsEKIGMuOQMAJYKJjBJPOSfIxZK29LkbwAvmF5Grdk5oGh4ZU6QyAAI-e7MTZmeAoEDZG5QaGbDgM6GYACE3wdIE1cjV8B1Sn18GIRtV8FNY1+GH8ACYAMxcaKQvDHN326HwdrwrJYJpJGAukDuz3Qn1qoA)

Comment: This is nothing short of an outstanding answer. Thank you for the time taken to explain, that was extremely helpful.