# How to access target type (and even property type?) as type parameter in decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I'm trying to implement a deep-watch property decorator in angular, this is the usage:

```ts
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class AppComp {

  @Watch(
    'a.b.c',
    function (last, current, firstChange) {
      // callback
    }
  )
  prop = { a: { b: { c: 'Hello' } } }；
}
```

I've almost done, except that the callback is typeless, its `this` is `any`, and its `last` and `current` parameters are `any` as well.

With generic I can provide these types to the callback function:

```ts
type PropType = { a: { b: { c: string } } };

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class AppComp {

  //    ↓ generic here
  @Watch<AppComp, PropType>(
    'a.b.c',
    function (last, current, firstChange) {
      // callback
      // this -> AppComp
      // last -> PropType
      // current -> PropType
    }
  )
  prop: PropType = { a: { b: { c: 'Hello' } } }；
}
```

But I think this pattern is verbose, because it is obvious in this context that the type of `this` in the callback function should be `AppComp`, and the `last` and `current` parameter should have `PropType` as their types.

Here is a simplified version of the definition of `Watch`:

```ts
interface IWatchDirectiveTarget {
  ngDoCheck?: Function;
}

interface CallbackFunction<ThisType, WatchedType> {
  (this: ThisType, last: WatchedType, current: WatchedType, firstChange: boolean): any;
}

export function Watch<ThisType, WatchedType> (
  path: string,
  cb: CallbackFunction<ThisType, WatchedType>
): (
  target: IWatchDirectiveTarget,
  key: string
) => void {
  return function (
    target: IWatchDirectiveTarget,
    key: string
  ) {
    target.ngDoCheck = function () {
      // some change detecting logic...
      cb.call(this, lastValue, currentValue, isFirst);
    };
  }
}
```

As you can see, I need to pass types into `Watch`, and pass these types again from `Watch` into `CallbackFunction`.

What I want is something like macro (just example, anything can reach the purpose is ok, macro is just the easiest thing I can think of) like `__CURRENT_CLASS_TYPE__` or `__CURRENT_PROPERTY_TYPE__`, and I can use them like this:

```ts
@Watch<__CURRENT_CLASS_TYPE__, __CURRENT_PROPERTY_TYPE__>(path, cb)
```

Looks ugly though, but at least the `@Watch<__CURRENT_CLASS_TYPE__, __CURRENT_PROPERTY_TYPE__>` can be treated as a whole and decoupled with class name and property name.

Or even better, some macro-like things in the definition of `Watch`, so it can be rewritten without outer generic type parameters:

```ts
function Watch (
  path: string,
  cb: CallbackFunction<__CURRENT_CLASS_TYPE__, __CURRENT_PROPERTY_TYPE__>
): (
  target: IWatchDirectiveTarget,
  key: string
) => void {
  return function (
    target: IWatchDirectiveTarget,
    key: string
  ) {
    target.ngDoCheck = function () {
      // some change detecting logic...
      cb.call(this, lastValue, currentValue, isFirst);
    };
  }
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish something like this?

Edit:

I've read this: [TypeScript property decorator that takes a parameter of the decorated property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590613/typescript-property-decorator-that-takes-a-parameter-of-the-decorated-property-t)

It looks possible to establish some kind of relationship between the type of value provided to the decorator factory and the type of decorated property...

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to **"half"** answer my question. Following the path of post [TypeScript property decorator that takes a parameter of the decorated property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590613/typescript-property-decorator-that-takes-a-parameter-of-the-decorated-property-t), I managed to erase the target type from the usage by changing its definition from **decorator factory** to **decorator factory factory**:

Definition:

```ts
interface Fn<TClass, TValue> {
  (this: TClass, last: TValue, current: TValue, firstChange: boolean): any;
}

export function DecoratorFactoryFactory<TValue> ():
  <TClass>(pathOrCb: string | Fn<TClass, TValue>, _cb?: Fn<TClass, TValue>) =>
  (target: TClass, key: string) =>
  void
{
  return function (pathOrCb, _cb) {
    return function (target, key) {
      // "hijack" ngDoCheck, change detecting logic...
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```ts
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class AppComponent {

  // two calls here, first call returns the decorator factory, second call returns the decorator
  @DecoratorFactoryFactory<number[] | undefined>()(
    'nestedProp',
    function(last, current, firstChange) {
      console.log('dbg change detected', this, last, current, firstChange);
    }
  )
  public prop;
}
```

I said "half" as I still need to specify the value type, but I think it's acceptable, because I use a string literal to specify the value's path, and I don't think TS has the ability to infer type from string literal.

1. automatic property type infer + value?.a?.b?.c
2. manual type + value

It's hard to say which is better.

This solution is not perfect because the double call in the usage is meaningless to user of this decorator, so I'm not going to accept my own answer. I hope someone with better understanding of typescript can come up with better answers (single call) or even solutions that can automatically infer the property type.